# Add dead zone to SwipeRefreshLayout Android

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to make the SwipeRefreshLayout have a small deadzone so that if the user scrolls to the top and keeps scrolling, it wont immediately try bring down the pull to refresh? i would like it to have a small dead zone because the pull to refresh is interfering with a view pager in the ListView.

if the user swipes the viewpager and moves their finger down very slightly through the drag, it starts to do the pull to refresh and the swipe motion is lost and the viewpager just resets its position.

i've tried doing something like this

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                p1 = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                p2 = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

            if(p1 != null && p2 != null && Math.abs(p1.y - p2.y) < 50) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

and

```
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED)
                p1 = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            else if(event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION)
                p2 = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

            if(p1 != null && p2 != null && Math.abs(p1.y - p2.y) < 50) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

but `p2` doesnt get set properly it seems so not sure what to do

Comment: you have to override canChildScrollUp

Comment: This is determined by the private `mTouchSlop` variable that is initialized in the constructor. You should be able to change it via reflection. Alternatively, you will need to override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` to return `true` only when you decide that it should be triggered (while also calling through to the super implementation so that it works as intended).